# How to detect where lines cross each other on form?

Tags: vb.net

I have added two line and a circle on form and now I wanted to check on which point they intersect each other?

Here is my code for drawing lines and circle on the form

**VB.Net**

```
Private Sub Panel_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Main_Panel.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 186, 210, 471, 210)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 330, 82, 330, 348)
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 210, 100, 240, 220)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that a joke? The lines obviously intersect at `(330, 210)`.

Comment: Would be easier to calculate it using analytic geometry?

Comment: Nico Schertler if i want to add a number on the right side of the intersecting line!
How can I do that
Please help me out?

Comment: With `e.Graphics.DrawString()`

Comment: thanks a lot for you response and help

Comment: @ Nico Schertler sorry for disturbing you again
I want to use scaling at point 330,210 where two lines are intersecting and i want to add scales 1-10  so that i can e.Graphics.DrawString() on that point e.g(2,5)
Is there any way to do this?